# Best practice: "If not immutable create copy"-pattern

Tags: scala, immutability, scala-collections

I have function which gets a `Seq[_]` as an argument and returns an immutable class instance with this `Seq` as a val member. If the `Seq` is mutable I obviously want to create a defensive copy to guarantee that my return class instance cannot be modified.

What are the best practice for this pattern? First I was surprised that it is *not* possible to overload the function

```
  def fnc(arg: immutable.Seq[_]) = ...
  def fnc(arg: mutable.Seq[_]) = ...
```

I could also pattern-match:

```
  def fnc(arg: Seq[_]) = arg match {
    case s: immutable.Seq[_] => { println("immutable"); s}
    case s: mutable.Seq[_] => {println("mutable"); List()++s }
    case _: ?
  }
```

But I am not sure about the `_` case. Is it guaranteed that `arg` is `immutable.Seq` or `mutable.Seq`? I also don't know if `List()++s` is the correct way to convert it. I saw many posts on SO, but most of them where for 2.8 or earlier.

Are the Scala-Collections "intelligent" enough that I can just always (without pattern matching) write `List()++s` and I get the same instance if immutable and a deep copy if mutable?

What is the recommend way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to pattern match if you want to support both,.  The code for `Seq() ++` does *not* guarantee (as part of its API) that it won't copy the rest if it's immutable:

```
scala> val v = Vector(1,2,3)
v: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3)

scala> Seq() ++ v
res1: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

It may pattern-match itself for some special cases, but you know the cases you want.  So:

```
def fnc[A](arg: Seq[A]): Seq[A] = arg match {
  case s: collection.immutable.Seq[_] => arg
  case _ => Seq[A]() ++ arg
}
```

You needn't worry about the `_`; this just says you don't care exactly what the type argument is (not that you could check anyway), and if you write it this way, you don't: pass through if immutable, otherwise copy.

Answer (score 1):

> What are the best practice for this pattern?

If you want to guarantee immutability, the best practice is to make a defensive copy, or require `immutable.Seq`.

> But I am not sure about the _ case. Is it guaranteed that arg is immutable.Seq or mutable.Seq?

Not necessarily, but I believe every *standard library* collection that inherits from `collection.Seq` also inherits from one of those two. A custom collection, however, could theoretically inherit from just `collection.Seq`. See Rex's answer for an improvement on your pattern-matching solution.

> Are the Scala-Collections "intelligent" enough that I can just always (without pattern matching) write List()++s and I get the same instance if immutable and a deep copy if mutable?

It appears they are in *certain* cases but not others, for example:

```
val immutableSeq = Seq[Int](0, 1, 2)
println((Seq() ++ immutableSeq) eq immutableSeq) // prints true
val mutableSeq = mutable.Seq[Int](0, 1, 2)
println((Seq() ++ mutableSeq) eq mutableSeq) // prints false
```

Where `eq` is reference equality. Note that the above also works with `List() ++ s`, however as Rex pointed out, it does not work for all collections, like `Vector`.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can overload in that way! E.g., this compiles fine:

```
object  MIO
{
  import collection.mutable

  def f1[A](s: Seq[A]) = 23
  def f1[A](s: mutable.Seq[A]) = 42

  def f2(s: Seq[_]) = 19
  def f2(s: mutable.Seq[_]) = 37
}
```

In the REPL:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.0 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_37).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import rrs.scribble.MIO._; import collection.mutable.Buffer
import rrs.scribble.MIO._
import collection.mutable.Buffer

scala> f1(List(1, 2, 3))
res0: Int = 23

scala> f1(Buffer(1, 2, 3))
res1: Int = 42

scala> f2(List(1, 2, 3))
res2: Int = 19

scala> f2(Buffer(1, 2, 3))
res3: Int = 37
```

Comment: For the case of wanting to defensively copy, however, you still have to pattern match in `f2(Seq[_]]`. e.g. after `val v : Seq[T] = Buffer(t1, t2, t3);` the call `f2(v)` calls `f2(Seq[_])`, not `f2(mutable.Seq[_])`, because call resolution is performed at compile time, based on the declared type of the parameter, not at runtime based on the runtime type of the parameter. In other words, Scala (like Java) uses static, not multiple, dispatch. When multiple dispatch is necessary, as here, we resort to pattern matching in Scala, or `instanceof` in Java.